# Can we point a microsoft teams app to a different environment instead of production?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a teams app published in the teams store where it is pointed to our production environment. The teams app contains a bot capability registered with the bot framework.

So the tenants who use our app in teams use their production credentials to login to the app and through the bot, ultimately API calls are invoked on our production gateway to serve the bot interactions.

These tenants also have non prod environments on our service where they would to test any new features to certify before going to production.

How can we achieve this configuration in our published teams app where a user would want to point the teams app to their non prod tenant on our service instead of production?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [Upload your app in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-publish-overview#upload-your-app-in-teams) to sideload an app for personal use, collaborating with your team, or testing and debugging.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this - Meghana-MSFT. The question is not about personal use or development. Its about customers using our published app in teams store but pointing it towards non production environment. Is there any way to specify configuration switching from prod to non prod environment or do we get a new teams app published which specifically points to non prod environment?

Comment: You need to create a new Teams app(Manifest) and publish it, which points to non prod environment.